# undefined function initializing taginput bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I'm try to implement [TagInput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/) for bootstrap 3 but when i try to inizialize it, it give me a error `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object #<TagsInput> is not a function`

Here is how i call the scripts

```
<script src='<?php echo base_url() ?>resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src='<?php echo base_url() ?>resources/js/bootstrap.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src='<?php echo base_url() ?>resources/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script> $('.tagplayer').tagsinput();</script>
```

form

```
<input type="text" class="tagplayer">
```

**Edit: I'm not currently work anymore with this plugin, i need suggest for accept the right answer.**

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem. May the author forgot to test after some revision.
Open bootstrap-tagsinput.js, and at the last line you can see the following code;

```
   $(function() {
       $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
   });
```

As you can see, in this js code, `tagsinput()` function is called.
Hence, including your call to `tagsinput()` in your code, there are 2 calls to `tagsinput()`.

As a result, at line 357 where registering `tagsinput()` function as a jquery plugin,
the initializing is failed.

To solve this, comment upper code. 
(But maybe you can use some functionalties, but not importan

Anyway, you need to include `bootstrap-tagsinput.css` too.

Comment: I suggest removing the data-role from the input if you're going to initalise the taginput manually rather than comment out the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

See this issue at GitHub: https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/52

A workaround that helped me:

```
<input type="text" id="tags">
<script>
    var tags = $('#tags')
    tags.tagsinput();

    tags.tagsinput('input').typeahead({
      prefetch: 'prefetch.json'
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
      tags.tagsinput('add', datum.value);
      tags.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
    }, $('input')));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems chosing the right plugin. At the end, I just implemented taginput myself, it's not hard.
Code :

HTML :

```
<p>Tags : </p><input type="text" name="irrelevant" id="tags" placeholder="add tag">
```

JavaScript(JS) :

```
var id=1;
function remove(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function addTag(e,name) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var entry=document.getElementById(name);
    entry.value=entry.value.toLowerCase();
    if (keyCode == '8' && entry.value.length==0) {
        if (entry.previousSibling.className=="btn btn-secondary margin") {
            entry.previousSibling.parentNode.removeChild(entry.previousSibling)
        }
        return;
    } 
    if (keyCode != '13' || !/[a-z]$/.test(entry.value) || document.getElementById(name+"_"+entry.value) != null) {
        return;
    }
    var id;
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(entry.value); 
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.setAttribute("id",name+"_"+entry.value)
    btn.className="btn btn-secondary margin"
    btn.setAttribute("onclick","remove('"+name+"_"+entry.value+"')")

    var insertedNode = entry.parentNode.insertBefore(btn, entry);
    entry.value=""
}
document.getElementById('tags').onkeypress=function(e) { addTag(e,"tags"); }
```

Basically, you are just checking whether keys are pressed and the entry is properly formatted, and accordingly adding tags, which are just buttons, before the entry. Only uses pure JS.