# TypeError:f[c] when adding a tag to bootstrap tags input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 input elements, in one i write some letters and autocomplete function fetches data from db and gets the results, once i select a result i want to add it as a tag in another input element.

```
$('@ID("#input_to")').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            jQuery.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("LoadAutocomplete", "Correspondence", new
            {
                                                                                        Area = "Correspondence"
        }))',
                request, response);
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            try {
                var elt = $('@ID("#input_tags_test")').tagsinput('input');

                elt.tagsinput({
                    itemValue: 'id',
                    itemText: 'text'
                });

                elt.tagsinput('add', { id: ui.item.id, text: ui.item.value });

                console.log(elt.tagsinput('items'));
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            jQuery('@ID("#input_to")').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
```

here is the html code

```
<input type="text" id="@ID("input_tags_test")" class="form-control bootstrap-tagsinput" data-role="tagsinput">               
            <input type="text" id="@ID("input_to")" class="form-control" name="recipientsName" placeholder="Search for someone...">
```

It works the first time only.. the second time it throws an exception

> TypeError: f[c] is not a function
>   ...lement).remove();b.itemsArray.length>0;)b.itemsArray.pop();b.pushVal(),b.options...

Answer (score 0):

i found out how to fix it, i should not define the tagsinput('input') twice .. im new to javascript and web development and i thought that as in C# the data member (elt in this case) would be destroyed and the destructor would be called after the function finished executing , but apparently this is not the case here, so adding a simple null check if statement solved the problem.

```
 if (elt == null) {
                    elt = $('@ID("#input_tags_test")').tagsinput('input');

                    elt.tagsinput({
                        itemValue: 'id',
                        itemText: 'text'
                    });
                }
```

and then happily ever after ;)

[this question helped me figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848130/undefined-function-initializing-taginput-bootstrap-3)